# Distinct ordering not in place

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temporary table making a list of names which are ordered by a different column, e.g.

```
@table:

John, 1
Mary, 3
Mary, 5
Mary, 7
John, 8
Kyle, 9
Brad, 10
```

when I call a simple `select * from @table`, that's what I get, but when I call a `select distinct name from @table` I get this:

```
Kyle
John
Mary
Brad
```

Why is it not using in-place ordering? Is this a sql quirk I don't know about? I would expect (and want) it to be:

```
John
Mary
Kyle
Brad
```

EDIT: Additional Question: Since I 'Ordered By' on the original table, is there a functional reason why it wouldn't persist?

Comment: Row order doesn't actually exist, absent an `ORDER BY`. If you need an explicit order, you must supply an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Data is not stored in a particular order. You have to specify the order that you want by using `ORDER BY`

Comment: Are we talking about SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, DB2, Access, ...?

Comment: sql server, and right now I'm getting Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 61
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: because I'm trying to order it on a table defining which names to select from, but since I'm not getting back the order-by column, I was hoping they would be in-place.

Comment: @Subliminy It might be easier to see your code. If you are getting an error about order by in a view, etc you should post the code that is generating that error message.  Right now answers are being given on a partial picture of the real issue. Please expand your original question with more details.

Comment: It turns out I simply can't do it without including my order-by columns into my select statement. thanks for the help. Here is the original code I was working with: `select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ProjectDescription) as MenuSortOrder , * from 
(select distinct menucategoryname as ProjectDescription from @tasks where menucategoryname in
(select menucategoryname from @tasks where isontasklist = 1 )[if I put an order by here it complains]) as taskprojects` I suppose that over(order by p) probably restructured my output as well

Comment: I just translated everything to human names, they're actually menu item names

Comment: Put the order by *after* `as taskprojects`.

Comment: yeah, I'm gonna have to select the columns in the query that I want to order by :/ Then that works, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `SELECT DISTINCT` you can't order by a column that's not being selected. The easiest way to do what you want is:

```
SELECT name FROM @table GROUP BY name ORDER BY min(id);
```